# stripe.net - how to process subscriptionService.Get with no results

Tags: c#, stripe.net

The stripe.com API only returns active subscriptions. I want to verify when I delete a subscription.

So this is going to return an error. I am not sure how to code for it.

I would prefer to make this call based on the subscriptionId. Will this cause an exception or will it return an error code?

Retrieving a subscription

```
var subscriptionService = new StripeSubscriptionService();
StripeSubscription stripeSubscription = subscriptionService.Get(*subscriptionId*);
```

Another options which is somewhat of a hack is to return all the subscriptions for the given customer and test to see if the subscriptionId was returned.

List all subscriptions for a customer

```
var subscriptionService = new StripeSubscriptionService();
IEnumerable<StripeSubscription> responses = subscriptionService .List(*customerId*);
foreach( var response in responses )
{
     if (response.subscriptionId == subscriptionId)
     {
         // subscription exists and was not deleted
         exit;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per their documentation, [https://stripe.com/docs/api](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types) they have 2 different APIs.  You're trying to use the RESTful API, which is for retrieving information on demand.

They also have a **[WebHooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) API**, which requires you have an endpoint listening on your site which can accept event notifications.  You configure these through your Dashboard with them.

The event type you're looking for specifically is probably the ***customer.subscription.deleted*** event, but there's a lot more you can do with them and I'd encourage you to explore all of those Webhooks.

I can't offer a code sample, as I don't use their service.

Comment: I agree that WebHooks provide the capability to receive notification on events associated with stripe transaction. I am trying to verify a delete, so I would have to setup a system to look for the event and if I do not see it for some time, then I would need to resubmit the delete request.

Comment: That is what you would do... however keep in mind that if your web service does not return a 200 OK response, it will queue the message and keep retrying.

Answer (score 0):

The strip.net example shows the subscriptionService.Cancel as a methed:

```
var subscriptionService = new StripeSubscriptionService();
subscriptionService.Cancel(*customerId*, *subscriptionId*);
```

But you can also use it as a function and it returns the subscription object.

```
var subscriptionService = new StripeSubscriptionService();
StripeSubscription stripeSubscription = subscriptionService.Cancel(*customerId*, *subscriptionId*);

If (stripeSubscription.Status != "canceled")
{
     //subscription not cancelled
     // take action
}
```

Per [Stripe API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription):

Returns:
The canceled subscription object. Its subscription status will be set to "canceled" unless you've set at_period_end to true when canceling, in which case the status will remain "active" but the cancel_at_period_end attribute will change to true.One of the fiels is .status , witch is set to canceled.